# Javascript file only load last file in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to load data from many Js file to a HTML file, data only load last file Js. I don't know why. 
This is my code :

```
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2 back data-choice"></div>
                <div class="top-title-detail-answer top-title col-sm-11"> 
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row " >
                <div class="question-area col-sm-12">
                    <img class="col-sm-2" src="./images/pantient.png" alt="" />
                    <div class="box-question col-sm-8">
                        <p>Q:</p>
                        <p id="question"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="answer-area col-sm-12">
                    <div class="box-answer col-sm-8">
                        <p>A:</p>
                        <p id="answer"></p>
                    </div>
                    <img class="col-sm-2" src="./images/doctor.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      <script src="js/main.js"> </script>
      <script>
        window.onload = interactiveCanvas.ready({ 
            onUpdate(data) {
                let dataNew = data.data;
                //back button
                let backActions = dataNew.components[0].buttons[0];
                let backTitle = backActions.name;
                let backAction = backActions.actions;
                let backType = backActions.type;
                document.querySelector(".back").innerHTML = `<button type="button" class="button btn-back " data-choice="${backType},common(),${backAction}">${backTitle}</button>`;
                //help title
                let title = dataNew.title;
                document.querySelector('.top-title-detail-answer p').innerText = title;
            } 
        })
        </script>
        <script src="js/dataQa.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Data only load from js/dataQa.js. If you know, Pls tell me why and help me load data from all file Js.

Comment: How do you check that only js/dataQa.js is loaded.

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example? Maybe using JSbin.

Comment: @as.if.i.code When i put <script src="js/dataQa.js"></script> above script interactiveCanvas.ready, interactiveCanvas.ready will load data, js/dataQa.js don't load